# Wordress Добавить символ ">" для родительских элементов меню

Tags: php, wordpress

Как добавить символ ">" для элементов меню, у которых есть дочерние элементы?

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, что тебе надо использовать `wp_get_nav_menu_items` функцию и переопределить меню.

Второй вариант: добавить в `css` атрибут `::after` и там сделать `content: '>'`

```
.nav-menu li > a:after {
    content: '>';
}

.nav-menu li > a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поигрался, получился такой код в итоге.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'css_for_nav_parrent');
    function css_for_nav_parrent( $items ){
        foreach( $items as $item ){
            if( __nav_hasSub( $item->ID, $items)) {
                $item->title .= '<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>';
            }
            }
        return $items;
    }

    function __nav_hasSub( $item_id, $items ){
        foreach( $items as $item ){
            if( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent == $item_id )
                return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```